# Как округлить число к числу шага на PHP и на JS?

Tags: javascript, php

Пример на `PHP`

```
$price = 242.54522003 // цена
$step = 1.00000000 // шаг цены
Должен быть результат: 242
```

Еще примеры:

```
$price = 242.54522003 // цена
$step = 0.00100000 // шаг цены
// 242.545

$price = 112.59920000 // цена
$step = 0.01000000 // шаг цены
// 112.59

$price = 112.59920000 // цена
$step = 10.00000000 // шаг цены
// 110
```

Округлять в меньшую сторону.

Comment: и? как пытался ?)

Comment: @Алекс Данилин, без результатно

Comment: `$result = $price - $price % $step`  . На `js` будет  тоже самое. `%` - оператор взятия остатка от деления

Comment: @zhurof, `float(2725.272) float(1) float(2725.272)` первое число цена, второе шаг. почему то все равно выводит `2725.272`

Comment: На php floor и ceil смотрите. Или round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
console.log(valStep(242.54522003,0.00100000))
console.log(valStep(112.59920000,10.00000000))
console.log(valStep(112.59920000,0.01000000))

function valStep(num, step) {
    let stepFloat
    if (step.toString().match('.') && step.toString().split('.')[1]) {
        stepFloat = step.toString().split('.')[1].length
    }
    if(stepFloat) {
        return   parseFloat(num - (num % step)).toFixed(stepFloat)
    } else {
        return parseInt(num - (num % step))
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно. Осталось только к php адаптировать